# Fire Event on Page Load

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am just getting started with Chrome Extensions. As an example I am using the "Page Redder" https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/samples#page-redder.

Because of `chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) {` it executes the red background when the `browserAction` button is clicked. How can I adjust this to make *every* page browsed to have a red background by default?

Here is full background.js file:

```
// Called when the user clicks on the browser action.
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) {
  // No tabs or host permissions needed!
  console.log('Turning ' + tab.url + ' red!');
  chrome.tabs.executeScript({
    code: 'document.body.style.backgroundColor="red"'
  });
});
```

Here is the manifest:

```
{
  "name": "Page Redder",
  "description": "Make the current page red",
  "version": "2.0",
  "permissions": [
    "activeTab"
  ],
  "background": {
    "scripts": ["background.js"],
    "persistent": false
  },
  "browser_action": {
    "default_title": "Make this page red"
  },
  "manifest_version": 2
}
```

Comment: Did you do any research?

Comment: Matter of fact, I did. I combed through the docs, stack-overflow, and through Google. While the answer may have been there, I (who am clearly not experienced with chrome extensions: see above) decided to try and reach out to the community for help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is Content Scripts; see the [documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts) and the [architecture overview](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/overview#arch).

There are several ways to inject a content script: you're already using one of them, using `chrome.tabs.executeScript`. This is called [*programmatic injection*](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts#pi), and allows you to run a content script at arbitrary time.

The other way is to register a content script [in the manifest file](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts#registration). It will then always* be injected in matching pages. A simple example for your needs:

```
"content_scripts": [
  {
    "matches": ["*://*/*"],
    "js": ["redder.js"],
    "run_at": "document_end"
  }
],
```

where redder.js is:

```
document.body.style.backgroundColor="red";
```

* Note that it will only be injected if a page is (re)loaded after fully loading the extension. It will not inject into tabs existing at the moment of enabling the extension.

---

In fact, in your particular case you don't even have to use javascript. You can inject CSS instead:

```
"content_scripts": [
  {
    "matches": ["*://*/*"],
    "css": ["redder.css"],
    "run_at": "document_end"
  }
],
```

where redder.css is:

```
body {
  backgroundColor: red !important;
}
```